# Malformed RSS feed

Tags: theme-development, feed

I am trying to connect my site's RSS feed to Mailchimp, but my feed doesn't pass basic RSS validation (http://testrtc.com/feed).

The reason for that is 3 empty lines at the beginning of the feed, which I am clueless as to where they came from.

I tried disabling all plugins but the result is the same. Assuming the culprit is my theme - where should I go search for it? My theme has no feed*.php files in it.

Comment: Most likely it is a problem with BOM character. make sure all your files are saved as plain utf-8 or ansi

Comment: No :-( All files are pure ANSI with no BOM character in there at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit.

functions.php had a few extra blank lines after the closing ?>

Once removed - it worked well